# Calculating vertices coordinates of a polyline connecting centers of two figures

Tags: geometry, algorithms, euclidean-geometry

Not a mathematician, but a programming student here.

Suppose there is a plane on which geometric figures (in this case simple rectangles) are arranged. We would like to connect two of them to each other using a polyline (or a line, if the situation allows). I'm thinking of setting points on the coordinate system, which would define vertices of such a polyline. These points would have to be located in such a way that none of the segments intersect the figures lying on the plane. The coordinates of the rectangles will be known. Would such calculations be possible? Or is there another way to determine such a path?

Comment: Slightly connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296532/305862

Answer (score 1):

You cannot in general in the case of an odd number of points (except for $n=3$). For example, it is already not possible for 5 points, because the resulting complete graph $K_5$ is provably [nonplanar](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4319746/305862).

In the even case, it is possible. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1571254/305862).